# Problem with under_score for deleting row in CodeIgniter4 and MySQL

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-4

All routes, controller and models are perfect.... Just when I use field name with "_" underscore in cat_id field I can't delete record while it works nice without under score ( only id ).

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_category` (
    `cat_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `cat_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
    `cat_desc` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
    `cat_status` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=12
;
```

**Model**

```
public function fnCategoryDelete($id){
        $this->where('cat_id', $id)->delete('tbl_category');
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public function categorydelete($id=null){        

        $this->cat_obj->fnCategoryDelete($id);
        return $this->response->redirect(site_url('category'));
        
    }
```

**Route**

```
$routes->get('categorydelete/(:num)', 'AdminControllers\CategoryController::categorydelete/$1');
```

**View**

```
<a href="<?php  echo base_url("categorydelete/".$item['cat_id']); ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
```

I am newbie so I can't figure out this one.

Comment: I don't see any code here that fails, only the table definition. Please include a full [mre] that would allow us to see the failure if we ran it ourselves.

Comment: @MatBailie Sorry for incomplete!
I pasted my code here!

Comment: What error are you seeing? Do you have development mode turned on? Have you tried to run the same query through something like phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @James Thank you for taking an interest in this. Actually I got the solution yesterday and it was my fault... I didn't set primary key field in my model.